# Free crossbrowser testing tool?

Tags: usability

I was looking for a tool to test my website in different browsers on different Operating systems.
Is there any free tool or service for this. Except for IETestter.
Basically to do a usability testing.

Comment: What does an online search suggest?

Comment: Do you mean free as in free beer or free as in free speech?

Comment: Yeah @JoãoFarias as like that

Answer (score 3):

VMWare allows you to setup virtual machines which can be accessed via GUI, if you wish. More info [here](https://techsviewer.com/how-to-install-mac-os-x-el-capitan-on-vmware-on-pc/).

[image]
[image]

For the binary of browsers, it would be a case by case situation - if you need browsers that don't come bundled with the OS, you may not find them around.

Note: You can also setup really old OSs, if you need (Windows 3.1 tutorial [here](https://grantwinney.com/installing-windows-3-1-in-vmware-player/)):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set-up Selenium Grid, it will enable you to distribute your test cases execution to perform on multi-browser & multi-OS testing.
You can refer the official documentation for more information

https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp

Comment: Not applicable, the question states it wants to do usability testing, not functional checking.